# Generating table inside a table row dynamically

Tags: javascript, c#, html, html-table

I have a web application, which uses HTML generic control to generate tables. I have a button in each row created dynamically. My question is, how can I add a new table under the corresponding row that holds the button?

Comment: So you have already code which generates tables dynamically, why did you stuck on creating another table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example using jQuery, manipulating tables in pure JS in my experience is a bit clunky.

[See on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8YNDr/)

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><button class="add-table">Add table</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><button class="add-table">Add table</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.add-table').click(function () {
        $(this).after('<table>\
            <tr>\
            <td>New table</td>\
            </tr>\
            </table>');
    });
});
```